How to make rollup + tailwind+vite library pass in CSP?
How to make rollup when generating dist folder after build be CSP friendly?
Rollup makes a single js file with makes everything inline, so I have problems to make it pass in CSP in my nextjs app.
I tried using separated css file with the extract: true, but then how to connect to the dist index.js? Also, about the scripts, cannot be inline.
